# regex - Java starts with * and ends with a newline (\n)

Tags: java, regex, compiler-construction

Basically this is what it looks like:

```
int abc = 10;
* this is a comment
```

so, I just want to find the `* this is a comment` so that I can remove it from the string. I have tried some examples although it doesn't seem to work. The idea is basically starts with `*` followed by any combination of words, numbers, or symbols (*anything really*) that ends with a newline `(\n)`.

Thank you.

Comment: show us what you have tried, let's try to start from those.

Comment: I have tried `.*[\\w\\d]\\n` but it seems to find everything

Comment: So you've got a really long String with multiple newlines in it, is that right?  So this will need to be a multi-line regular expression.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Now that you mention it, Java comments don't even start with `*`, they start with `//` or `/*`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It looks like OP is inventing his own language - hence the compiler-construction tag.

Comment: If you're writing a compiler, you should be removing comments as part of the tokenization phase, not as a step of its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern `^\*.*$` should work here:

```
String line = "Not a comment\n* This is a comment\n*This is also a comment\n";
line += "Not a * comment.";
String pattern = "^\\*.*$";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

while (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
}

Found value: * This is a comment
Found value: *This is also a comment
```

Not much to explain here, except that `*` is a regex metacharacter, and if you want to use it as a literal, then it needs to be escaped by a backslash.

### Demo

Comment: I'm using pattern matcher

Comment: @XavierJohanis And? The regexp is fine also for use with a pattern matcher.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Edited it, thanks.  I needed to use `Pattern.MULTILINE` to get the engine to recognize my input string as a collection of lines.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem BTW if you're wondering the genesis of that pattern error, I had initially answered with `String#matches()`, where the pattern implicitly matches the entire string (hence no anchors are needed).  Then the OP told me he wanted a matcher, so I changed, but my test data didn't include your edge case :-)

Answer (score 3):

Regex in this case IMO is an overkill. Split the lines by "\n", then for each line simply check it with `line.startsWith("*")` would do the filtering.

Comment: thank you for your answer I really appreciate it, however it is much easier to use regex so I can remove that comment portion of the string.

Comment: With regex it does the filtering, but this check improves readability of the code, especially if you are not familiar with regex. Cheers.